# How do i align mirrored objects

Tags: mirror

How can I make a carbon copy of an item from the right hand side of my model, so the dimension's are the same? And after that has been done, how can I have it automatically snap in on the left hand side, so that the position of these items is exactly identical? In other words, I don't want to move anything myself manualy, what I need is to mirror, and after mirroring use some function in blender to place it in exactly the same position on the left hand side of my model, without me touching it. I have heard of the terminology snapping and aligning, is there such functionality in blender?

Comment: Your question is a bit long for how confusing it is. Do you mean like this ? https://imgur.com/a/ZVvlZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i snap and align multiple objects on opposite sides?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/how-do-i-snap-and-align-multiple-objects-on-opposite-sides)

Answer (score 1):

If it is something symmetrical, you may also be able to get away with using an array, and offsetting it however you see fit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set a rotational point for your model:
Add > Empty > Plain Axes

To your model:  Add Modifier > Mirror
Mirror Object : Empty